# Model doesn't appear in Solid Sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

I am a blender newbie here trying to sculpt this model but it doesn't show in Solid mode and also can't do anything in other shading mode .

What am I doing wrong ? [image]

Comment: From your video it's hard to tell what's going wrong. But...you're using Blender 2.8. That's currently unfinished software. Sometimes it has hickups. Maybe you've encountered one. Does the problem persist when you close and restart Blender? Do you run the newest blender 2.8?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by accident. I was using skin modifier. Looks like I just had to apply the modifier before sculpting.